# What is the effect of the variance on a sequence of cumulative product?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We randomly draw numbers from a normal distribution with mean equals $mu$ and variance equals $var$.

We draw the values: $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, ...$

Then, we construct a sequence made of the cumulative product of these randomly drawn numbers.

$(x_1), (x_1\cdot x_2), (x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3), ... $

The expected values of any number of this sequence depends not only on $mu$ but also on $var$. What is the formula for the expected value (given $mu$ and $var$) of say the 15th value of this sequence?

Comment: "The expected values of any number of this sequence depends not only on mu but also on var." Sorry but if the $x_k$ are independent, I fail to see why.

Comment: if $\sigma=0$, a_2 is $\mu^2$. If $\sigma!=0$,, let's say at the first draw we get a value that equals $\mu+e$ and then we draw a value that equals $\mu-e$, then a_2 is $(\mu+e)\cdot (\mu-e)=\mu^2-e^2$. Does it make sense? The higher the variance, the lower are the values in the sequence as @Henry said

Comment: But you do not get "$\mu+e$ then $\mu-e$", you get $\mu+e$ then $\mu+e'$ where $E(e)=E(e')=0$ and $(e,e')$ is independent hence $E(ee')=E(e)E(e')=0$. For every value of the variance. (And I have no idea about what the answer you mention is talking about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $X_i$s are independent, then $E(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = \mu^n$.