# Product of randomly drawn numbers

Tags: probability-distributions, products, expectation

Here are two code line to run in R:

> prod(rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=0)) # (1)
>
> prod(rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=0.2)) # (2)

$prod(..)$ returns the product of a sequence. The sequence it given by $rnorm(n, mean, sd)$. This function $rnorm(...)$ return n values randomly drawn from a normal distribution with $mean$ and $sd$.

The only things that differ between the two lines in the $sd$. Line (1) is totally deterministic as $sd=0$ and therefore it always returns the value $1$. Line (2) is not determinstic and almost always (in 90% of the cases I'd say!) return a value that is lower than $1$.

- Why is it so?
- What is the expected value of line (2)?
- In what percentage of the cases does line(2) returns values greater than $1$

Comment: $(1+\varepsilon)(1-\varepsilon) = 1- \varepsilon^2$ - that's what's going on.

Comment: Also, $\prod X = \sum \log X$ and $\log$ is not symmetric. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Comment: Is there an R group that this would be more suited to?

Comment: I am not interested in R programming. I used these two lines of code only to make my question more straigthforward. I am interested of the mathematics behind such calculations. The expected value of products of values drawn from a normal distribution.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė True, but the argument fails because $|1-\varepsilon^2|\gt1$ when $|\varepsilon|$ is "large".

Comment: OP: Did you simply read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545504/6179) to one of your previous questions? If you do not, you will ask again and again basically the same question and people will have to point again and again that "the almost sure behaviour of an i.i.d. product is not described by the common expectation of the factors but by the expectation of their logarithm".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence $(x_k)$ is i.i.d. and $P[x_1=0]=0$, when $n$ is large, $\left|\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right|=\exp(n\xi_\sigma+o(n))$ almost surely, where $\xi_\sigma=E[\log |x_1|]$. This follows from the law of large numbers applied to the i.i.d. sequence $(\log |x_k|)$, plus the identity $\left|\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\right|=\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log |x_k|\right)$.

In your case (2), one assumes that each $x_k$ is a normal random variable $(1,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma=0.2$, then $\xi_\sigma=E[\log|1+\sigma z|]$ where $z$ is standard normal. What happens is that $\xi_\sigma\lt0$ when $\sigma=0.2$ hence $\prod\limits_{k=1}^nx_k$ converges to zero almost surely.

We checked numerically that $\xi_\sigma\lt0$ when $\sigma=0.2$. Note that the function logarithm is concave, hence $E[\log u]\lt\log E[u]$ for every nondegenerate positive random variable $u$ (this is Jensen inequality, with a strict inequality sign when the distribution of $u$ is not Dirac). But this only shows that $\xi_\sigma$ is "not too positive" when $\sigma$ is "not too large", not that $\xi_\sigma\lt0$ always.

As a word of caution against some too simple arguments, note finally that, for some larger values of $\sigma$, indeed $\xi_\sigma\gt0$, the transition occuring between $\sigma=1.55$ and $\sigma=1.56$ (and surely the zero of the function $\sigma\mapsto E[\log|1+\sigma z|]$ has a name...).